# Hide blank or Null Field Options in Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I am trying to edit the code below to hide the (blank) values in the field options list. I think because I am using a data model, I am getting a little tripped up with the syntax. I am getting the error message, "Unable to get the PivotItems property of the PivotField class"

```
Sub hi()
 With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("[Range 2].[Goal].[Goal]")
        .PivotItems("(blank)").visible = False
End With
        
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: So what is happeing, do you get an error, is it not hiding... Please provide the details so we can help you.

Comment: oh good point! I am getting an error message. - Unable to get the PivotItemsproperty of the PivotField class

Comment: So debug the code, add a watch on ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields see what is in there. You should be able when working as described figure out how to get to right entry..

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to solve for this by selecting the Pivot Table entirely and attempting to find all of the blanks from the data that is being pulled into the Pivot.

1. Select a column in your worksheet that contains blank rows.
2. Press Ctrl+F on the keyboard to open the Find & Replace box.
3. Select theFind tab and click on Options to open the advanced menu. Don’t input anything in the Find what box.
4. Check the box beside Match entire cell contents.
5. Select Sheet from the drop-down menu of Within.
6. Select Values from the drop-down menu of Look in.
7. Click on Find All button to get all the blank cells in the selected range.
8. Select all these rows by Ctrl+A.
9. Close the Find box.
10. Delete the rows by clicking on the right button, and selecting the Delete option.

I hope this helps! You can view the whole article that has screenshots on how to do this [here](https://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/how-to-delete-blank-rows-in-excel/).

Comment: I don't understand how this helps me to update the script above :(

Comment: This could be helpful with an small script.

Comment: This should be an small script or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest adding an slicer where the default view could be an unselected option for the blanks values.

```
Dim slcCache as SlicerCache    '' Object to manipulate the slicer
Set slcCache = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("SlicerName") '' Assign object

With slcCache
    .ClearManualFilter
    .SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = False '' False value to unselect
'' I do not remember if this is the actual name for an empty value, 
'' but you could find it or replace it by the index that should be 1
End with
```